# Size of MYI index smaller on slave server

Tags: mysql, database, myisam

I've recently altered a huge `MyISAM` table (80 million entries) by adding a new value in an enum field. After I did this I've checked the health of the table on 2 slave servers which are used to replicate the master server. 
I've noticed that `MYI` file is much smaller on one of the slave servers. I've repaired the table with `myisamchk` and `REPAIR` but the size of the index has not changed.

Please see below the results returned by running `myisamchk -dvv` on these 3 servers for "Keyfile length":

```
Master Server
Auto increment key:              1  Last value:              80098340
Data records:             79375556  Deleted blocks:                 0
Datafile parts:           79375556  Deleted data:                   0
Datafile pointer (bytes):        6  Keyfile pointer (bytes):        6
Datafile length:        9635014668  **Keyfile length:       18945252352**
Max datafile length: 281474976710654  Max keyfile length: 288230376151710719
Recordlength:                 1110

Slave Server 1
Auto increment key:              1  Last value:              80097611
Data records:             79374828  Deleted blocks:                 0
Datafile parts:           79394418  Deleted data:                   0
Datafile pointer (bytes):        6  Keyfile pointer (bytes):        6
Datafile length:        9635788652  **Keyfile length:       18024821760**
Max datafile length: 281474976710654  Max keyfile length: 288230376151710719
Recordlength:                 1110


Slave Server 2 - Here the size of Keyfile is much smaller
Auto increment key:              1  Last value:              80098312
Data records:             79375002  Deleted blocks:                 0
Datafile parts:           79375002  Deleted data:                   0
Datafile pointer (bytes):        6  Keyfile pointer (bytes):        6
Datafile length:        9634942908  **Keyfile length:       11092404224**
Max datafile length: 281474976710654  Max keyfile length: 288230376151710719
```

What could possibly cause such a significant difference?

Comment: Question: The Slave with the smallest MYI, was that Slave recently setup or what it the last Slave to be setup ?

Comment: I don't know exactly when this slave server was setup, but it was configured few years ago. If forgot to mention that I didn't checked the size of MYI file on this slave server before I ran the repair for it. Is it possible that repair/myisamchk rebuilt the index with such a big size difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ran a repair on the a MyISAM, it should reduce the size of the `MYI`. Why ?

When a mysqldump creates and load a MyISAM table, think of the mechanical steps to make `mytable`:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable ...
LOCK TABLE mytable ...
ALTER TABLE mytable DISABLE KEYS; (shuts off updates to non-unique indexes)
INSERT INTO ...
INSERT INTO ...
.
.
.
ALTER TABLE mytable ENABLE KEYS; (rebuild all indexes)
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

During the `ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE KEYS`, you run `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`

You will see the info of that process say `Repair by sorting`

When done you should have an MYI with 95% of more BTREE nodes filled to capacity.

Why does so much space vanish when you repair it ? Look at the opposite case.

You are loading a table in numerical order on some auto_increment id. Loading data in some ordered fashion produces lopsided key distribution in BTREE indexes. In some cases, all nodes can be up to 45% fragmented.

EXAMPLE: If you have a binary tree (the worst BTREE) loaded in order, you get a binary tree leaning all the way to the right that should look like a linked list with a negative slope.

I once mentioned this crazy phenomenon in my DBA StackExchange posts

- `Aug 03, 2011` : [When should I rebuild indexes?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4283/when-should-i-rebuild-indexes/4285#4285)
- `Jun 28, 2012` : [Benefits of BTREE in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20047/benefits-of-btree-in-mysql/20114#20114)
- `Oct 26, 2012` : [How badly does innodb fragment in the face of somewhat out-of-order insertions?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27678/how-badly-does-innodb-fragment-in-the-face-of-somewhat-out-of-order-insertions/27685#27685)

Running a `REPAIR TABLE` in the mysql client, running `myisamchk -r` or reloading a mysqldump of a MyISAM should produce a smaller MyISAM index file always.

Comment: Should I run a repair also on the other slave server and on master? Does this improve table performance?

Comment: If you are doing heavy reads from that MyISAM table, then repair them. Make sure you are not running `myisamchk -r` against a live `.MYI`. Otherwise, the `.MYI` will quickly become corrupt. If the table is live, you should be running `REPAIR TABLE mytable;`. If the table is for archival purposes and occasional reports, you can hold off for a while.